# Isolating fat jar dependencies in a classloader

Tags: java

What's the best way to isolate dependencies from a loaded fat jar from the application that loads it?

**Consider this code:**

```java
JarByteClassloader loader = new JarByteClassloader(jarByteArray);
Class c = loader.loadClass(classToLoad);
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(loader);
JarEntryObject jarEntry = (JarEntryObject) c.newInstance();
```

The above code loads jar from a file/network. From there a Jar class loader is used to the methods to execute from the loaded jar. This approach works but my concern is how to isolate dependencies from a loaded fat jar from the current application that loads it.

Let's say the main application has a dependency on `com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre1` and the loaded fat jar have a dependency on `com.google.guava:guava:28.0-jre1` it should not conflict or clash.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html